# Can DateComponentsFormatter format fractional seconds?

Tags: macos, foundation, nsdatecomponents, nsdatecomponentsformatter

I want to print, e.g., the value 1.5 as "1.5 sec", like Safari's timeline does, and I'm trying to use DateComponentsFormatter for it.

Unfortunately, its `.allowedUnits` only goes down to `.second` (even though the enum has `.nanosecond`).  I tried setting `.allowsFractionalUnits = true`, but I'm still getting "0 sec".

Is there any way to get fractional seconds out of DateComponentsFormatter?

Comment: Which method do you use to format what?

Comment: Willeke: The only method which accepts the parameter `1.5`: `string(from:​ Time​Interval)`.

Comment: The time interval is internally translated into NSDateComponents.

Comment: Willeke: Yes, I assumed that was the case.  That's the logical way for them to have implemented it.  So?

Comment: Did you find a way to get "1.5 sec" from the DateComponentsFormatter? Can't be true that Apple forgot to implement this.

Comment: @Daniel Sadly, it appears to be very true, as of iOS 13.3.I haven't found a way of getting a localised output of "1.5 sec" from DateComponentsFormatter. It will only output "1.5". Super-annoying.

Answer (score 2):

For positional units style, `DateComponentsFormatter` can be used together with `NumberFormatter` to get locale-aware string.

```swift
func format(_ seconds: TimeInterval) -> String {
  let components = DateComponentsFormatter()
  components.allowedUnits = [.minute, .second]
  components.allowsFractionalUnits = true // does not work as expected
  components.unitsStyle = .positional
  components.zeroFormattingBehavior = .pad

  let fraction = NumberFormatter()
  fraction.maximumIntegerDigits = 0
  fraction.minimumFractionDigits = 0
  fraction.maximumFractionDigits = 3
  fraction.alwaysShowsDecimalSeparator = false

  let fractionalPart = NSNumber(value: seconds.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1))

  return components.string(from: seconds)! + fraction.string(from: fractionalPart)!
}

print(Locale.current) // ru_RU (current)
print(format(600.5))  // 10:00,5 <- note locale specific decimal separator
```

Unfortunately, using this method for other date styles is even more hacky.